# Minipage maximum height

Tags: minipage

I want to make template for texts of different length with minipage having maximum height of 62 mm. If text isn't very long, minipage must have its natural height. Is it a way to do it?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

Foo

\vfill

\noindent\adjustbox{center,fbox}{
\begin{minipage}[t][62mm][t]{\textwidth}

\lipsum

\end{minipage}
}

\newpage

Foo

\vfill

\noindent\adjustbox{center,fbox}{
\begin{minipage}[t][62mm][t]{\textwidth}

Bar

\end{minipage}
}


\end{document}
```

[image: Minipage with maximum height needed]

Comment: @Sigur For what? I need minipages of different height with maximum of 62 mm.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry.

Comment: What should happen, if the natural height of the box is larger than 62mm? Which depths of the box are allowed?

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek, nothing. In that case text should be replaced.

Comment: What's the purpose of a maximum height, if nothing should happen, when the box is larger? Which text should be replaced when by what?

Comment: Okay, I will try to explain. That's all for old and stupid standard that post-soviet libraries using -- "Annotated card template". This card has maximum height, so if a text of annotation is too long, you need to rewrite this text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox{\strangeminipagebox}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{strangeminipage}{O{\textwidth}}
 {%
  \begin{lrbox}{\strangeminipagebox}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\ht\strangeminipagebox+\dp\strangeminipagebox<62mm\relax
    \framebox[#1]{\usebox{\strangeminipagebox}}%
  \else
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \fbox{%
        \vrule height \ht\strangeminipagebox
               depth \dimexpr62mm-\ht\strangeminipagebox\relax
               width 0pt
        \hspace{\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
      }%
    }%
    \makebox[#1]{\usebox{\strangeminipagebox}}%
  \fi
 }

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{strangeminipage}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{strangeminipage}

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{strangeminipage}[.5\textwidth]
Bar
\end{strangeminipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! could you explain me {O{\textwidth}} parameter? How can I change it for some another variable?

Comment: @web-stranger `O{\textwidth}` means that the environment gets an optional argument, with default value `\textwidth`. I used it in the second example, to show that it reduces the width.